# For loop not incrementing properly

Tags: java, for-loop

I have this code but when the else branch executes, the `i` is not incremented and I can't find out why...

```
while(rs.next()){
  tableAktivityBuilder.append("<tr><td><input type=\"text\" class=\"rowAktivita\" value=\""+rs.getString("name")+"\"/></td><td>");
  StringBuilder tmpBuilder = new StringBuilder("<select class=\"course\"><option value=\"-1\" type=\"\"></option>");
  for(int i = 0; i < prurezove.length+odborne.length; i++){
    int idKompetence = rs.getInt("id_kompetence");
    if(rs.getString("typ_kompetence").equalsIgnoreCase("p") && i < prurezove.length){
        if(idKompetence == prurezoveIds[i]){
          tmpBuilder.append("<option value=\""+idKompetence+"\" type=\"p\" selected=\"selected\">"+prurezove[i]+"</option>");
        }else{
          tmpBuilder.append("<option value=\""+idKompetence+"\" type=\"p\">"+prurezove[i]+"</option>");
       }
    }else{
      log.info("kompetence = o");
      log.info("i = "+i);
      int awa = prurezove.length+odborne.length;
      log.info(""+awa);
      if(idKompetence == odborneIds[x]){
          tmpBuilder.append("<option value=\""+idKompetence+"\" type=\"o\" selected=\"selected\">"+odborne[x]+"</option>");
      }else{
          tmpBuilder.append("<option value=\""+idKompetence+"\" type=\"o\">"+odborne[x]+"</option>");
      }
      x++;
    }
  }
  tableAktivityBuilder.append(tmpBuilder);
  tableAktivityBuilder.append("</select></td><td>");
  if(rs.getInt("cena") != 0){
    tableAktivityBuilder.append(rs.getInt("cena"));
  }
  tableAktivityBuilder.append("</td></tr>");
}
```

the log output is

```
kompetence = o
i = 4
5
kompetence = o
i = 4
5
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: and then it stops or does it continue looping at i=4 forever?

Comment: It simply means that the else branch is executed only once per iteration of the `while(rs.next())` loop. Use a debugger, and execute the statements one by one to understand what happens precisely.

Comment: @OGHaza It stops because of IndexArrayOutOfBounds exception

Comment: what the others said, and IndexArrayOutOfBounds is probably because x gets incremented too high. Try printing x and odbourne.length. if x == odbourne.length then you'll get an OutOfBounds when you reference odbourne[x]

Comment: @OGHaza The answer from Alex Suo is right. Thank you anyway!

Comment: that's what I meant by "what the others said"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just your out while loop executed twice and your inner loop always reach else {} when i == 4 and then exit.

Comment: Oh my... I should slap myself... I spent about hour trying to find what am I doing wrong... Thank you! I'll accept your answer ASAP

Comment: Nah it's just exp :-) Good luck and happy coding!